# Не могу зайти в backend

Tags: php, yii2

делаю приложение на yii2-advanced, настраиваю доступ к бэкэнду для админа.
после того как выставляю права сбивается ссылка на админку и выскакивает ошибка, а в адресной строке фигурирует старая директория, из которой я удалил файл index.php и директорию site.
подскажите, где следует посмотреть пути?

```
31.08.2018 imgsrv/admin/site/login - (такого пути нет)
http://imgsrv/admin/site/login 1/1
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request "/error". in /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:537
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(108): yii\base\Module->runAction('/error')
#1 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpExcep
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#3 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\base\InvalidRouteException: Unable to resolve the request: site/login in /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:128
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#1 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/login', Array)
#2 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#3 /var/www/imgsrv/backend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#4 {main}
Next yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Страница не найдена. in /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/imgsrv/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 /var/www/imgsrv/backend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

ошибка появляется после добавления следующих строк:

```
  'access' => [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['index', 'create', 'view', 'update', 'delete'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['admin'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

upd: подюключение AccessControl производит ошибку. но почему?

Comment: Возможно какие-то данные закэшировались, поэтому и ошибки

Comment: нет, проблема была в другом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в ненастроенных **`config/main.php`** для **frontend** и **backend**, которые были разные в разных файлах, а должны были быть **одинаковыми**:

```
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-site', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'advanced-site',
    ],
```

Прописать эти строки в обоих файлах.